# Jenkins JobDSL Parameter getting overwritten by configure block

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

On our Jenkins instance we are using a mix of plugins where JobDSL API is available for a few and not available for others due to which we are having to create these using the configure option.

In such a circumstance;

The configure block seems to be overwriting the existing parameter if I place the configure block out of the parameter closure (see code below); or

The ordering goes wrong (the booleanparam is listed second after the Extended Choice parameter that gets generated) if I place the configure block inside the closure - any ideas what could be going wrong?

Ideally within the parameter section I want the Boolean parameter to appear first followed by the Extended Choice parameter

```
job('example') {
  parameters {
    booleanParam('<name>, <boolenvalue>')
  }
  configure {
    project->
      project / 'properties' << 'hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty' {
        parameterDefinitions { 'com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended__choice__parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition'
          {
            name '<name>'
            quoteValue 'false'
            type 'PT_MULTI_SELECT'
            value '<values>'
            multiSelectDelimiter ','                
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just must not generate a second `ParametersDefinitionProperty`. Instead add the parameter below the existing `parameterDefinitions`:

```
job('example') {
  parameters {
    booleanParam('<name1>')
  }
  configure { project->
    project / 'properties' / 'hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty' / parameterDefinitions << 'com.cwctravel.hudson.plugins.extended__choice__parameter.ExtendedChoiceParameterDefinition' {
      name '<name2>'
      quoteValue 'false'
      type 'PT_MULTI_SELECT'
      value '<values>'
      multiSelectDelimiter ','                
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks daspilker - will try this out and report back

Comment: works if we have only plugin in the configure block - does not seem to work if I have two plugins in the configure block - seem to be getting a `java.lang.ClassCastException: <2nd_plugin>cannot be cast to hudson.mode1.JobProperty` error - any idea what I could be missing

Comment: Ok ignore that - that error was due to something else - in any case my question stands - can't figure out how to add two plugins under configure block without affecting the one that is outside the configure block and using the DSL API

Comment: If you following oops concepts for your job-dsl project then you could have two different classes for each.